# Trying to associate two children collections to a parent collection using populate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate, database

'Im trying to have an array of patients Objectids and an array of data(information about doctor) objectids inside the doctors collection. This is the beginning of the code then I got lost. I think I want to use something like this `Doctor.find().populate('patients data')`. Then if someone could show me how to access the information that would be great.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/population")

        var doctorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
            name : String,
            patients : [{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "Patient"}],
            data : [{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "Data"}]
        })

        var patientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
            name : String
        })
        var dataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
            income : String
        })

        var Doctor = mongoose.model("Doctor",doctorSchema );
        var Patient = mongoose.model("Patient", patientSchema);
        var Data = mongoose.model("Data", dataSchema);

        var doc1 = new Doctor({"name" : "doc1"})
        doc1.save(doc1, function(err, doc){
            if(err){ 
                console.log(err)
            }else{
                console.log("saved")
            }

        })



app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("listening on 3000");
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the information, the `app` should be able to receive requests; a 'get' method needs to be defined on the `app` object:

```
app.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  var doctorID = req.params.id;

  Doctor
    .findOne({_id: doctorID})
    .populate('patients data')
    .exec(function(err, doctor) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.send(doctor);
    });
});
```

Comment: what exactly is populate doing here? Is this adding the the objectId of patients and data to the the appropriate arrays in the doctor collection?

Comment: It uses the IDs to fetch the corresponding patients and data objects then adds those objects to their appropriate arrays. You'll need to add the IDs to the `patients` and `data` arrays manually, in a 'POST' request.

Comment: when you say it "uses the IDs" . Are you referring to the IDs of the patients and data collection or the ID of the doctor collection?.

Comment: I meant the IDs of the `patients` and `data` collections, yes.

Comment: So I could create a patients document by having the data filled in with a post handler and body-parser. That will create a document with an objectID. and that will allow me  to use .populate("patients") in this case? other wise it wouldn't work because patients needs to have an ObjectID right?

Comment: Yes. `patients` needs to contain at least one ObjectID.

Comment: Thanks for your help by the way. I'm missing something. The `exec` in your code I think will send the doctors collection with all the patients in the patients collection to the patient field's  array value?  this I think makes the  document the same as not doing the separating of the collections at the beginning. am I wrong or right? thanks for your help

Comment: The `exec` just executes the query. It returns the `doctor` object with the `patients` and `data` arrays filled out.

Comment: Maybe this is good because it only puts everything together at a get request. otherwise it will be seperate EDIT:: maybe that's a good use case for populate. I was trying to figure out the practical use of populate.

Comment: Could you mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem? This will help the next person who has a similar problem.